# How to create a new directory in chrome app

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, filesystems, google-chrome-app

I am trying to build a utility that creates a folder, sub-folder and a few files. Initially I tried chrome extensions but then realised that they dont have access to [chrome.fileSystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) so I am trying it in a chrome app

The best resource I could find was https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/filesystem-access which uses chrome.fileSystem to create files but creating a `dir` is still not clear and the [chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem#method-getWritableEntry) aren't much helpful either as there was no clear definition of a `fileEntry`. Can someone help me to use this api to create folders and also how is this different from using `fs` like done [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/blob/master/samples/storage/main.js)

Something like fs.requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT ... wouldn't work for me since it gets saved to a sandbox in a weird format. Please help me out here.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemDirectoryEntry

Comment: @DanielHerr this wouldn't work, due to sandboxing thing, read the edit